# what will be best storage for storing contacts and email in android app

Tags: android

Suggests me some good storage type to store contacts from mobile and email contact fetched from web. This should get stored in app itself with less space it could take.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An SQLiteDatabase may work, here is a link to the tutorial I used:

http://www.androidwarriors.com/2016/02/android-sqlite-database-tutorial-sqlite.html

Comment: thanks @Tom James , what would be the next preferable storage for this case?

Comment: You may be able to determine which is best for yourself by reviewing the content in this link: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Answer (score 1):

Your data storage options are the following:

Shared Preferences:
Store private primitive data in key-value pairs.(if your data is few kbyte then use this option).

Internal Storage
Store private data on the device memory.(File, document is used to save the this storage )

External Storage
Store public data on the shared external storage.(File, document is used to save the this storage )

SQLite Databases
Store structured data in a private database.(Recommend for your)

Network Connection
Store data on the web with your own network server.